# Is it possible to run a "postwatch" script after a long-running "watch" script

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, watch, npm-scripts, sigint

I have a project that uses a `watch` script to watch files and compile them as they change.

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "node-sass ... -watch",
    "postwatch": "npm run clean:artifacts"
}
```

I am needing a way to run the `postwatch` script after the process is terminated so that I can clean up some artifacts created while watching. I understand that killing the watch process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> terminates in a way that the `watch` command never really exits in the way that would trigger the `postwatch` script. I'm looking for alternatives.

Note: I've tried the following to no avail:

```
"watch": "node-sass ... -watch ; npm run postwatch",
```